# What does flow between two nodes mean

Tags: graph-theory

In *Formulations and a Lagrangian relaxation approach for the prize collecting traveling salesman problem* I read the following in subsection *2.1. Subtour elimination*:

"For each $v ∈ \bf V$, the maximum flow between $r$ and $v$ on a graph with set $\bf V$ of nodes and set
$\bf A$ $= \{(i, j) ∈ \bf A : x_{ij} > 0\}$ of arcs where $\bf x_{ij}$ is the capacity of arc $(i, j) ∈ \bf A$ is computed."

As far as I understand a flow graph is a graph that has a root. But what does **flow between two nodes** mean? I can find no proper definition on the internet nor in the article itself.

Comment: It's probably max flow when $r$ is source and $v$ is sink.

Comment: It is the value of a solution $f$ to an instance $(V,A,x)$ of the [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).